# On hover change animation with transition

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I need to change the animation with a transition effect. That is change first transition to another with a flow. When I tried for the same the animation changes with a fast change as in below snippet. Is there any way to animate the change in animation. I have tried the below code.

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/76/08/0b760848c89b9e4abd03f74f19419498.jpg');
}
.bubble{
    top: 50px;
    left: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: translatey(0px);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.bubble span {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 85px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}

.bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
    0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 0 24px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: ripples 1s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.bubble:hover {
 transition: all 2s;
 animation: tofixed 4s forwards;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-color: transparent;
}
.bubble:hover:before {
  animation-play-state: running;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}


@keyframes float {
 0% { box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); transform: translatey(0px) scale(0.9); }
 50% { box-shadow: 0 25px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transform: translatey(-20px) scale(1); }
 100% { box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); transform: translatey(0px) scale(0.9); }
}

@keyframes tofixed {
 to {  transform: translatey(0px) scale(0.9); }
}


@keyframes ripples {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
      0 0 0 24px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 0 0 32px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
  <span class="bgviolet">ODOSTORE</span>
</div>
```

In the above snippet you can see the change in animation is instantly when I hover on it.